# Rails HAML helper to display a list item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am having difficulty getting my helper to display a list item. The markup looks like the following:

```
   - @bars.each do |bar|
      <% display_bar(bar) %>
```

The actual helper looks like the following:

```
module MyHelper
  def display_bar(bar)
    type = bar.type
    concat(%li.type)
    concat(%b some text)
    concat(%i some more text)
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I am not sure if you left it out in the original code, the `=` in `<%= display_event(bar) %>`, but if that is the case, it should be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Such things has to be implemented via partials. Or see 5.
2. `<%` won't show you anyting. **You're in Haml**. It's ERb stuff (but even there it wouldn't have shown anything: you'd forgotten the `=` sign, it should have been `<%=`).
3. About `concat(%li.type)`: you cant put your markup inside your Ruby code. Ruby knows nothing about your `%li` "code".
4. Amokrane Chentir already mentioned.
5. You're trying to reinvent the wheel. Rails already provides magnificent helper for such simple cases.

Take a look:

```
  = content_tag_for(:li, @bars) do |bar|
    %b= bar.title
    %i= bar.id
```

**UPD:** `content_tag_for` sets styles/ids for each `li` tag based on the current model instance that makes it easy to implement styling/scripting in the future.

Comment: This is fine, but my content has stuff like %li.class and I need to get the class from the instance of bar. I don't think this example accommodates for that.

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct answer, but bar in this case is a hash, not a regular ActiveRecord model or anything. so I still need to figure out how to get the right list item class as the class lookup needs to happen in a helper. Right now it's just a constant such as 0,1,2,3 and I need to map that to something like 'foobarclass'

Comment: *but bar in this case is a hash, not a regular ActiveRecord model* -- tried by myself. Not even close to Hash. I tried to put `= bar.class` and I got `MyModel` The `@bars` I instantiated as `@bars = MyModel.all`. Check your code again and take a look at docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RecordTagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag_for

Answer (score 2):

1. The name of your helper is `display_bar` not `display_event`.
2. You should use `=` instead of `<% %>`

   ```
   - @bars.each do |bar|
       = display_event(bar)
   ```

**EDIT**

Oops didn't read carefully the content of `display_bar` method, as @jdoe mentioned you can't use Haml markup syntax in your Ruby code.

Comment: That was just a typo in me typing up the question. Using ``=`` works, but my use of concat() I believe is still not proper.